# WSPBuilder obfuscated dll

Tags: sharepoint, obfuscation, wspbuilder

I am using WSPBuilder to build a wsp file for sharepoint. One of my referenced dll's is obfuscated with .Net Reactor. When building the wsp project, this dll is not recognized, the WSPbuilder is throwing an error. I am not with the solution of installing this dll manually as it should be part of a complete setup on a sharepoint farm with multiple web front ends.

Any solution or idea for a workaround?

The error i am getting is this:
Unable to resolve assembly 'WSPBuilder.XmlSerializers, Version=0.9.8.206, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2b778c59697d7d9e', please use DLLReferencePath to point to the directory where this DLL is located.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved with WSPBuilder ver. 0.9.8.0406

See [Unable to resolve assembly WSPBuilder.XmlSerializers](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=9729)